# Conjugacy classes of a nonabelian group of order $p^4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

Apologies in advance for the long text! I will explain what I have done so far, and then I will present my question.

Consider a nonabelian group of order $p^4$, where $p$ is a prime. Then, the center $Z(G)$ cannot have order $p^3$ or $p^4$, since both these cases would lead to the contradiction that $G$ is abelian. So we consider:

**Case I:** Order of $Z(G)$ is $p^2$     i.e.,$|Z(G)|=p^2$

The class equation is given by $|G|=|Z(G)|+\Sigma|G:C_G(g_i)|$, where the $g_i$ are representatives of the distinct conjugacy classes of G not contained in the center $Z(G).$ I deduced that for each $g\notin Z(G),$ $|G:C_G(g)|=p.$ So the class equation becomes $p^4=p^2+kp,$ where $k$ is the number of distinct conjugacy classes not contained in the center. This gives $k=p^3-p$ and hence the number of conjugacy classes of $G$ is $p^3+p^2-p$

**Case II:** $|Z(G)|=p$

I was able to prove that for any $g\notin Z(G),|G:C_G(g)|=p$ or $p^2.$ That means that, a conjugacy class not contained in the center can have size $p$ or $p^2.$

**My question is:** Is there any way to determine how many conjugacy classes of size $p$ is there, and how many conjugacy classes of size $p^2$ is there?

I would really appreciate any help regarding this question. Thank you!

Comment: Well unless there are classes of both sorts you can see what the answers would be; of course that leaves open the question of existence. And if there do exist elements whose centraliser has order $p^3$ can one prove that $G$ is the split extension of a $\mathbb{Z}_p^3$ by a cycle which acts as a single Jordan block, and $p$-powers to the centre?

Comment: I’m sorry, I don’t know anything about Jordan blocks. Could you please elaborate on your comment. 

Thank you very much!

Comment: @ancientmathematician I don't think that's right. All groups of order $p^4$ with centre of order $p$ have some elements (in fact $p^3-p$) with centralizers of order $p^3$, and others with centralizers of order $p^2$.

Comment: Thanks @DerekHolt, I am just finding it difficult to think of other examples.

Comment: [This](https://math.wvu.edu/~capantea/pdf/conjugacy.pdf) might contain some useful results for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a quick summary of what is happening - I have to admit that I did some computer calculations first and worked out what was happening.

It is not hard to see that a group $G$ of order $p^4$ with class two has centre of order $p^2$, so if $|Z(G)|=p$ then $G$ has class three and $|[G,G]|=p^2$.

Since the order of the automorphism group of a group of order $p^2$ is not divisible by $p^2$, we must have $|C_G([G,G])| = p^3$.

Then the elements in $C_G([G,G]) \setminus Z(G)$ have centralizers of order $p^3$ and classes of order $p$. There are $p^3-p$ such elements, and the remaining $p^4-p^3$ elements have centralizers of order $p^2$ and lie in classes of size $p^2$.

To see that a group of class $2$ has centre of order $p^2$, suppose not and let $G$ be a counterexample. Then $|Z(G)|=p$ and $G/Z(G)$ is abelian of order $p^3$. Then the commutator map $(g,h) \to [g,h]$ induces a bilinear map $G/Z(G) \times G/Z(G) \to Z(G)$.

Since $G/Z(G)$ cannot be cyclic, it is isomorphic to $C_p \times C_p \times C_p$ or to $C_p \times C_{p^2}$.

In the first case, let $a,b,c$ be inverse images in $G$ of generators of the three copies of $C_p$, and let $Z(G) = \langle z \rangle$.

Suppose that $[a,b]=z^i$, $[a,c]=z^j$, $[b,c]=z^k$ with $0 \le i,j,k < p$. We cannot have $i=j=k=0$, so suppose that $i \ne 0$. Then $[a,b^tc] = z^{it+j}$ and so choosing $t = -j/i\bmod p$ gives $[a,b^tc] = 1$. Similarly we can find $s$ with $[b,a^sc] = 1$, and then $a^sb^tc \in Z(G)$, contradiction.

The case $G/Z(G) = C_p \times C_{p^2}$ is easier, because the $p$-th power of the inverse image in $G$ of a generator of the $C_{p^2}$ factor is in $Z(G)$.

Comment: I am trying to understand your solution. What did you mean by "G has class 4"? Thank you for your time!

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. I meant class three - that's nilpotency class.

Comment: Thank you so much. This makes sense. I have a couple of questions though. 1) Could you please elaborate a bit more on "It is not hard to see that a group G..." I don't know if this is obvious but I'm having a difficulty proving this statement. 2)Could you please give me some hints on how to construct a group of this type. Once again, thank you for your time. @Derek Holt

Comment: I have added some more details for the "it is not hard to see" claim. I'll answer your other question when I have time.

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate it. @DerekHolt